# "What is it(,) to be a hero?"

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, commas, emphasis, dummy-it

My friend and I have gotten into a rather passionate debate about whether Karen Paige's monologue at the end of season two of Daredevil was written in a grammatically correct fashion.

On screen, we can see that her monologue opens with the sentence:

> What is it, to be a hero?

I contend, with no academic backing whatsoever, that this is a perfectly valid grammatical construction. In fact I even contend that "To be a hero, what is it?" would be grammatically correct as well, despite being incredibly stilted.

On an intuitive level, I feel 'To be a hero' is what 'it' refers to, and Karen Paige's rendering of this sentence is a re-ordering of "To be a hero, what is it?" that places the definition of the pronoun 'it' after the clause that employs it.

My friend, on the other hand, points out that none of the common grammar guides surrounding commas actually contain rules that cover this construction, and furthermore feels from ***his*** intuition that the sentence is confusing because it sounds as though it could be interpreted as Karen Paige asking someone named 'to be a hero' the question 'what is it.'

My friend feels strongly that the, ***correct*** way to write this sentence is without the comma: 'What is it to be a hero', however I object to this, because in my mind, it changes the emphasis of the sentence.

My opinion is that with the comma, because the sentence is in a reverse order, extra emphasis is placed on "What is it", whereas in my friend's version the emphasis is on "to be a hero". My friend doesn't feel this is the case.

Comment: Both versions are 'grammatically correct' - whether or not to use a comma is just a stylistic choice.

Comment: Maybe influenced by French, where questions often begin "Qu'est-ce que c'est"

Comment: @KateBunting That's my argument, but is there a definitive source my Friend and I can reference that can back this up?

Like, is there a well-known rule this slots into that we don't see?

How do I make a convincing argument for its grammaticality without simply saying "it ***is*** grammatical, I swear!"

Comment: I don't think it's "grammatical". To my mind, the comma is irrelevant. But I'll accept *What is to be a hero?* on the grounds that the complement X in *What is X?* can be an infinitive-based expression as well as a noun (same as *I want **a drink / to drink*** or *He knows **John / to keep quiet***). I'd prefer *What is **being a hero**?*, though.

Comment: There's a book [What is it to be human](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/What_is_it_to_be_Human/Rm8QAQAAIAAJ?hl=en), which suggests no comma or pause, and various things you might hear in speech "What is it, that thing on the table?" "What is it, some kind of beetle?", where a comma indicates a pause followed by further explanation. All these are grammatical. But time and again it has been said that there are few (if any) rules for commas.

Comment: This seems similar to reduplication as in: "John, he's a nice fellow." I'd probably analyze your sentence as an example of apposition, but I'm sure that others will have other interpretations.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan "John, he's a nice fellow" is not an apposition, though.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I agree; the two situations are somewhat similar but not the same.

Comment: @KateBunting The comma is not just a stylistic choice. There's two possible grammatical structures there. The OP's is a right dislocation, which we'd expect to have a comma. In that case the word *it* is a referential pronoun. Their friend's reading is an extraposition construction, where *it* is a meaningless dummy pronoun. We definitely wouldn't use a comma there. There might be a case that whether the comma is there in the first is a matter of style. But the friend's sentence cannot have one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But the sentence isn't "*What is to be a hero?*"

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: To repeat myself - *To my mind, the comma is irrelevant* (and it certainly doesn't reflect a pause in speech). And these attempts to describe the syntactic structure strike me as equally pointless, because the text *isn't syntactically valid in the first place.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Are you saying that you'll accept "What is to be a hero?" but not "What is it to be a hero?" ?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: Well, I'm not a big one for "syntactically valid / invalid" anyway, but yeah - I *do* find that extraneous pronoun "awkward". You wouldn't ask *What is **it** [,] a bird or a plane or Superman?* as a single sentence, would you? Or *What is **it** [unknown word]?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, but the plane/bird etc examples are noun phrases. We often use a dummy *it* when we don't like to use a clause in a particular position. Then we shunt that clause down to the end of the sentence. For example "It's good to be on time" or "I love it when a plane comes together". We don't say "It's good a dinner"., or "I hate it a bird", but that doesn't make the original *it*-extraposition sentences bad! The other version of the sentence is the "Who's he, that Fumblefingers character?" type.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: I covered that in my first comment, and I'm not about to be persuaded otherwise.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Strange that native speakers have got strong and diametrically opposite views on which is grammatical! Your shorter version is ungrammatical for me. Stuart F, Marc and Kate seem to find OP's sentence grammatical. (Shrugs)

Comment: Imho English doesn't really have *any* succinct natural phrasing along the lines proposed, for the exact senses of (1) *What does it **mean** to be a hero?* and (2) *What is being a hero **like**?* (which are subtly different questions *syntactically*, but it's too hard for me to figure out if they could feasibly mean different things in the real world).

Comment: @FumbleFingers From COCA: "What is it to live the good life?" / "What is it to be a human?" / "What is it to be a father?" / "What is it to be a novelist?" /  "What is it to die but to stand naked in the wind and to melt into the sun." / "What is it to be a philosopher?" / "What is it to be a child if not to think and want as a child does? /"What is it to have one's young life intruded upon by the very worst aspects of this intractable conflict between Israelis and Palestinians?" / "What is it to be a storyteller?" - a sample. Seems it's definitely grammatical for *some* esteemed authors.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: I never suggested otherwise. I don't like the cited usage as an example of a "syntactically valid utterance", and I particularly don't like it with ***it***. I also don't like it *semantically*, because of that possible ambiguity between "external description" (what does it ***mean**?*) and "internal perception" (what's it ***like**?*). I'm well aware people often say things that don't meet *my* definition of "grammatical". But that definition has little to do with whatever I was taught about grammar - it's just how my "inner grammarian" reacts, which I can't change

Comment: The meaning is clear. The question and the extensive discussion are about how to define grammar, not about meaning. Grammar is not a fixed system handed down from above. It is the formalising of the patterns that may be seen in the expression of meaning. The discussion shows that the formalising in this case is still at the stage of discussing pattern. As such it is a matter of opinion so I vote to close the question.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that the use of a comma does indeed change the emphasis of the sentence. However, that is the only difference between the sentences. There is nothing grammatically incorrect about either of the sentences. As mentioned in the comments, this is something that is up to writer regarding the way in which they intend the question to be read (and interpreted).

Based on the way in which Karen says the sentence in the show, it makes more sense to me that they meant for there to be a comma. Although, as mentioned, if it weren't for the dialogue, both would be equally valid.